# Set initial value for parameter with roslaunch

Tags: parameters, ros

I'm working on an assignment on the turtlesim tutorials from ROS.

The launch file `ex74.launch` launches 4 nodes:

> -the turtlesim node (animates the movement of the turtle)
>   - pubvel (publishes random angular and linear velocity commands)
>   - vel_filter (subscribes to the topic on which pubvel publishes. This node filters the angular velocities and publishes only the messages
>   with an angular velocity smaller than the parameter max_ang_vel)
>   - vel_printer (prints the filtered velocities)

The scripts and the launch file are given at the end of my question.

The goal is now to set an initial value for `max_ang_vel` and change it from the command line.

However, when I run the launch file, i get the following error:

[link to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6m7p.png)

Also all angular and linear velocities from `vel_filter` and `vel_printer` are 0.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**ex74.launch**

```
<launch>
<node   
pkg="turtlesim"
type="turtlesim_node"
name="turtlesim"
/> ## launch animation of turtle

<node 
pkg="me41025_74"
type="pubvel"
name="publish_velocity"
required="true"
launch-prefix="xterm -e"
output="screen"
/>  ## launch pubvel

<node 
pkg="me41025_74"
type="vel_filter"
name="filter_velocity"
required="true"
launch-prefix="xterm -e"
output="screen"
>  ## launch vel_filter
<param name="max_ang_vel" value="0.1" />
</node>

<node 
pkg="me41025_74"
type="vel_printer"
name="print_velocity"
launch-prefix="xterm -e"
output="screen"
/>  ## launch vel_printer

</launch>
```

**pubvel**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_velocity");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/cmd_vel", 1000);

srand(time(0));

ros::Rate rate(2);
int count_pubvel = 1;
while(ros::ok()){
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
msg.linear.x = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);
msg.angular.z = 2*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) - 1;

pub.publish(msg);

ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);

rate.sleep();
}
}
```

**vel_filter**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <turtlesim/Pose.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float linx, angZ;

void filterVelocityCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist& msg){
   //Using the callback function just for subscribing  
   //Subscribing the message and storing it in 'linx' and 'angZ'
   linx = msg.linear.x;      angZ = msg.angular.z;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "filter_velocity");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turtle1/cmd_vel",1000,&filterVelocityCallback);
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/pose", 1000);

const std::string PARAM_NAME = "~max_ang_vel";
double maxAngVel;
bool ok = ros::param::get(PARAM_NAME, maxAngVel);
if(!ok) {
ROS_FATAL_STREAM("Could not get parameter " << PARAM_NAME);
exit(1);
}

  ros::Rate rate(2);

  while(ros::ok()){
     geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
     msg.linear.x = linx;     msg.angular.z = angZ;

     if (angZ < maxAngVel){
       ROS_INFO_STREAM("Subscriber velocities:"<<" linear="<<linx<<" angular="<<angZ); 

        pub.publish(msg);   
     }  
     rate.sleep();   
  } 
}
```

**vel_printer**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <iomanip> 

void printVelocityReceived(const geometry_msgs::Twist& msg){
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Filtered velocities:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

ros::init(argc, argv, "print_velocity");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turtle1/pose",1000,&printVelocityReceived);

ros::spin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code.

1.) The error you are getting is there because you are listening to the wrong message type. In the [turtlesim documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim) you can see that the topic you are listening to in the *vel_printer* is not of type *geometry_msgs::Twist* as you wrote, but of type *[turtlesim/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/api/turtlesim/html/msg/Pose.html)*. This is the reason for your error. Also I suggest you use ConstPtr for receiving messages. Your callback function for the turtle pose should therefore be:

`void printVelocityReceived(const turtlesim::Pose::ConstPtr& msg){
    ... do your magic ...
}`

2.) The parameters. In the launch file you are publishing the parameter *max_ang_vel* to the parameter server. Because you are doing this inside the  tags you are therefore making it private for this node. In order to read the private parameters of a node you need to specify another node handle, a private one. Then you can use [node handle's functions](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) to access the parameter.

Example of this:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
     ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
     ros::NodeHandle nh; // public node handle
     ros::NodeHandle nh_privat("~"); // private node handle

     // Get the parameter.
     nh_privat.param("max_ang_vel", maxAngVel, 0.0);
     // first argument: name of the parameter on the parameter server
     // second argument: variable to save it to
     // third argument: default value if the parameter is not set
 }
```

And for changing the maxAngVel from the console, you can just use standard C++ and read the input into the console and then change the variable accordingly.

Comment: Hello maetulj. Thanks for your response. The second part seems to work now, but the first part gives  an error that  a ) is expcted after Pose::. How can i solve this?

Comment: hey @user7845839 can you perhaps write the full error from the compiler? Because I checked and turtlesim::Pose should have ConstPtr defined...